# CoreData + NSDate [SWIFT]

Tags: swift, swift3

Здраствуйте!
У меня есть таблица, core data и nsdate из core data.
Мне нужно делать fetch request чтобы достать эти данные, а потом вывести результат, который я достал в table view cell. Вот мой код, но с кодом у меня ну чуть проблемы - у меня не выводит результат.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let game = games[indexPath.row]

    if let getDate = game.gameDate {

        let dateformatter = DateFormatter()

        dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy h:mm"

        let time = dateformatter.string(from: getDate as! Date)

        cell.textLabel?.text! = time

    }
```

А вот как я сохранил дату

```
@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let game = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Games", into: context)

    var date = Date()

    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()

    dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy h:mm"

    game.setValue(time, forKey: "gameDate")

    appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Как я понял вы хотите записать в core data объект Date а записываете строку, поменяйте ваш метод:

```
@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let game = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Games", into: context)

    var date = Date()

    game.setValue(time, forKey: "gameDate")

    appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```

---

**Вариант 2**

Или второй вариант, если у вас в core data все-таки должна лежать строка. Тогда просто поменяйте :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let game = games[indexPath.row]

    if let getDate = game.gameDate {

        cell.textLabel?.text! = getDate

   }
```

И не совсем понятно что у вас за переменная time но, как я понимаю ваш метод записи должен выглядеть так:

```
 @IBAction func startGame(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
     let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

     let game = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Games", into: context)

     var date = Date()

     let dateformatter = DateFormatter()

     dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy h:mm"

     let time = dateformatter.string(from: getDate as! Date)

     game.setValue(time, forKey: "gameDate")

     appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```

Comment: Сначала вы сохраняете это как дата, да? Но как я потом могу записать это в tableViewCell если это дата? У меня вот такой вопрос - Как это сохранить как строку, а не как дату в первом методе? Просто когда я изменил код как вы сказали у меня при принте в cell выводит ошибку

Comment: если у вас в кор дате у поля "gameDate" стоит тип Date то читайте первую половину ответа и меняйте метод "startGame". Если у вас там тип "String" то читайте вторую половину и меняйте метод "tableView". Судя по вашему комментарию вам подойдет вариант 2. Не меняйте ваш метод для записи данных а просто поменяйте метод tableView. потому как если вы сразу получиет строку из кордаты то нет смысла опять пытаться привести ее к типу Date и отформатировать